# How to set background image in this type

Tags: android, layout

I want to set background image which is transparent in this music player but I don't know how to set this can someone help me to make picture transparent

Comment: Can you provide more context on what you are trying to do? Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a png file or try this :

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
myImage.setAlpha(127); //value: [0-255]. Where 0 is fully transparent and 255 is fully opaque.
```

or try this:

```
    <ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/blah"
android:alpha=".75"/>
```

Comment: setAlpha() is deprecated